# Is there any night transportation in Sumatra (Indonesia)?

Tags: transportation, indonesia

I have started travelling in the northern part of [Sumatra (Indonesia)](https://www.google.co.id/maps/place/Sumatra/@0.0763834,98.1402552,6z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x2e2aad6120570311:0x1def4d17e789deb4) & noticed there was not many (if any) night transportation.

I suppose it's because the quality of the roads is "on & off" (from what I have experienced so far) & it might just be too dangerous.

Is there part of Sumatra where night transportation is common?

Comment: There are busses and trains that run at night. Travelling by car or motorbike (or ojek, something like a motorbike taxi) might be dangerous at night in certain parts of sumatra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course there are. It is even very common, at least for long distance run

For some lines (such as Medan-Singkil), it is even the only option available. The thinking is that there is less trafic at night and that, especially on a twisty mountain road, you see better the incoming car at night.

I took night transports (long distance taxi, minibus or big bus) on line going from Medan to Singkil, Dumai and Pekanbaru. Each of those is at least 10 hours long.

Comment: Do you have any details about the companies running such means of transportation? Where the pickup point is? What's the cheapest? Some links too would be great. ;)

Comment: I am not in Sumatra now and those info are hard to find on the web.
I assume you are in Medan. For big buses, just go to the various terminal. People of the street or becak drivers can often give you those info. For taxi and minibuses, you'll find many outlets next to Mejid Raya. If you especially want to go to Singkil (and Pulau Banyak) phone Dermawan +62 81360170808

Comment: @Madlozoz regarding Dermawan, the phone number you provided is out of date, this is the correct one: +62 82166457040

Comment: @JoErNanO for mini buses, there is a company called Sampri. It's Sumatra... Hence everything is pretty 3rd world like, and info is very hard to find online, I would not expect any company websites, but a phone number with some approximate information at best :)

Comment: Please add this information to your post. ;)

Comment: @ adrien Be
Dermawan Email is dmawan_skl76@yahoo.com